# TensorFlow build failed on win10 ( error C2338 )

Tags: tensorflow, build

I try build TensorFlow on win10. Sources download 02 november 2018.
Error

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\ucrt\assert.h
>   .\tensorflow/compiler/tf2xla/cpu_function_runtime.h(71): error C2338:

```
std::pair<uint64, uint64> Encode() const {
static_assert(sizeof(*this) == 16, ""); <----- assert
uint64 upper = Pack(kind(), size_);
uint64 lower = entry_param_number_;
return {upper, lower};
```

}

Bazel config

```
build:xla --define with_xla_support=true
build --config=xla
build --action_env TF_NEED_OPENCL_SYCL="0"
build --action_env TF_NEED_ROCM="0"
build --action_env TF_NEED_CUDA="1"
build --action_env CUDA_TOOLKIT_PATH="c:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v9.2"
build --action_env TF_CUDA_VERSION="9.2"
build --action_env CUDNN_INSTALL_PATH="c:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v9.2"
build --action_env TF_CUDNN_VERSION="7"
build --action_env TF_CUDA_COMPUTE_CAPABILITIES="6.1"
build --action_env TF_CUDA_CLANG="0"
build --config=cuda
test --config=cuda
build:opt --copt=/arch:AVX
build:opt --define with_default_optimizations=true
build --config monolithic
build --copt=-w --host_copt=-w
build --verbose_failures
build --distinct_host_configuration=false
build --experimental_shortened_obj_file_path=true
build:v2 --define=tf_api_version=2
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? (I'm also having exactly the same problem)

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to look at:

1.) It looks like you are telling the compiler to find the cuDNN in the same path as CUDA. I downloaded cuDNN separate and unzipped it to C:\tools\Cuda\

2.) I had an error similar to this and I set cuDNN version to 7.3.1 (not just 7) and opted to NOT use the C++ eigen bypass.

Answer (score 0):

I download another release - r1.12 -another error was occurred (in protobuf - invalid type cast). I just download the binaries for cuda 9.2 from 
https://github.com/fo40225/tensorflow-windows-wheel/blob/master/1.8.0/py36/GPU/cuda92cudnn71sse2/tensorflow_gpu-1.8.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl